# Why wont my vote reducer populate UI correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm having to strange behaviors with a feature in my application.

<strike>First of I'm not sure why but when I vote on a score my item gets updated at `/` but it gets pushed down into the end of the list.</strike>

See video for example : https://streamable.com/zlwmw

And secondly when I'm in detailed view I'm receiving an error:

`Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): state.filter is not a function`

Would really appreciate pointers!

#### Update:

Fist issue is solved now my post item stays in the same location.

---

My application is built as follow:

#### Repo:

https://github.com/petterostergren/readable_udacity

### Action

```
export function pushVotePost(option, postId) {
  const request = API.postVotePost(option, postId)

  return dispatch => {
    request.then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({ type: POST_VOTE_POST, payload: data, meta: postId })
    })
  }
}
```

### Reducer

```
import {
  POSTS_GET_POSTS,
  POST_VOTE_POST,
  POSTS_GET_POST,
} from '../actions/actionConstants'

const posts = (state = [], action) => {
  const { payload } = action
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_VOTE_POST:
      return [...state.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id), payload]
    case POSTS_GET_POST:
      return payload
    case POSTS_GET_POSTS:
      return payload
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default posts
```

### component 1 `/`

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { getPosts } = this.props
    getPosts()
  }  

return _.map(posts, post => {
      return (
        <div className="post-container" key={post.id}>
          <PostComponent
            key={post.id}
            postId={post.id}
            title={post.title}
            body={false}
            readirect
            author={post.author}
            voteScore={post.voteScore}
            category={post.category}
            timestamp={post.timestamp}
          />
        </div>
      )
    })

export default connect(
  state => ({
    posts: _.filter(state.posts, ['deleted', false]),
  }),
  {
    getPosts,
  }
)(Posts)
```

### component 2 `/:category/:postID`

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { getPost, getComments, match } = this.props
    this.props.getPost(match.params.postId)
    this.props.getComments(match.params.postId)
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { posts } = state
  return {
    comments: state.comments[ownProps.match.params.postId],
    posts,
  }
}

const { posts } = this.props
    return (
      <PostComponent
        key={posts.id}
        postId={this.props.match.params.postId}
        title={posts.title}
        body={posts.body}
        readirect={false}
        author={posts.author}
        voteScore={posts.voteScore}
        category={posts.category}
        timestamp={posts.timestamp}
      />
    )

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPost, getComments })(PostDetails)
```

Comment: i think your updated vote goes to the end of the array is because in your `reducer` you spread the array and place the new `payload` in the end of it. `return [...state.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id), payload]`

Comment: @Sag1v Could I switch the order somehow?

Comment: @Sag1v Ohh wait that was easy changed it to `[payload, ...state.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id)]`

Comment: yup you can find the index of the updated item, use slice up to the index number to remove it, spread the result,  insert the updated item and then use slice for the rest of the array. if you want i can post an example. i recommend watching dan abramov's (the author of `redux`) tutorial about it [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread)

Comment: your change will make it be always first now :)

Comment: Oh.. guess I have to use the slice method then! nicely spotted =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157023/discussion-between-petter-ostergren-and-sag1v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first issue you are spreading the filtered array and placing the updated item (`payload`) in the end of the array.

```
return [...state.filter(item => item.id !== payload.id), payload]
```

When you compose the new array you should place the updated item in the same index position.
Something like this:

```
const itemIndex = state.findIndex(item => item.id === payload.id);
  const nextState = [
    ...state.slice(0, itemIndex),
    payload,
    ...state.slice(itemIndex + 1)
  ];
  return nextState;
```

As for your second issue, the error you are getting is because the state data structure is changed, it is not an array of `Posts` anymore, but a `Post` object. And objects doesn't hold a `.map` function.
You see, your `posts` is handling both `Posts` and `Post`.

At the first page when you change votes you are dealing with actions like `POSTS_GET_POSTS` that returns a `state` of an array of posts, same with `POST_VOTE_POST`.

But when you enter the edit page you invoke the block of:

```
case POSTS_GET_POST:
      return payload
```

The payload in this case is a single `Post` object and not an array of `Posts`, so now you state structure is an object and not an array, and when you again change a vote you hit the `POST_VOTE_POST` condition which expect to deal with a state in the shape of an array  but the state is now an object actually. Hence you get the error

> `state.filter` is not a function

As you know, objects doesn't have a `filter` function, arrays does.

Comment: Ohh now I see it helped me to see in an environment i was a bit more use to, thanks

Comment: I see, so I need to make sure that it stays as an array somehow, will have a look at it